# What is my mistake to border a specific range up to the last row with an entry?

Tags: excel, vba

i tried on more ways to border the result of the variable `V2` in Column E but it doenst work. You can see my tryings as a comment within the code. Has anyone an idea? Thanks

---

By the way is it possible to figure out `End(xlUp)` & `End(xlDown)` just by a Macro?

**Update**

This i could figure out by pressing shift +Cntrl + ArrowDown

---

```
Sub Duplicate()
    
    Dim nA As Long, nD As Long, i As Long, rc As Long
    Dim s As String, j As Long
    'Dim LastRow As Long
    'Dim rng2 As Range
    
    
    
        Range("A:A").Copy Range("D1")
        Range("B1").Copy Range("E1")
        Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        rc = Rows.Count
        nA = Cells(rc, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'grün
        nD = Cells(rc, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'gelb
       
           For i = 2 To nD 'gelb
            v = Cells(i, 4) 'gelb
            V2 = "" 'rot
            For j = 2 To nA 'grün
                If v = Cells(j, 1) Then 'orange
                    V2 = V2 & "," & Cells(j, 2) 'rot / ZU UMRANDEN
                End If
            Next j
            Cells(i, 5) = Mid(V2, 1) 'rot / 1 = Start erstes Zeichen
        Next i
        
        'LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        'Range("E:E" & LastRow).Borders (xlInsideHorizontal)
        
     
        'Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E:E", ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        '   rng2.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    
        'With rng2.Borders()
        '       .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        '      .ColorIndex = 0
        '     .TintAndShade = 0
        '    .Weight = xlThin
            
    'End With
    
    Debug.Print
        
End Sub
```

**Update**

How it is right now

[image]

How it shall be

[image]

**Update**

final need had been like this

[image]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of how you expect it to look?

Comment: sure i just added the pics, thanks. Important the sheets change by data ..so i can not just say border "E2:E6"

Comment: If I understand what you want to achieve then there is a better way to achieve it...

Comment: you mean the code at all or specific my problem?

Comment: Posting an asnwer. One moment

Comment: Do you only needs adding borders to the cells in the range "E2:E6"? Range to dynamically be determined, of course... If yes, your question is extremely wrong formulated and that's why I suppose that it is something else I am missing... Can you clarify this aspect?

Comment: i think you dont miss something. Here in this exapmle yes E2:E6 has "just" do be bordered. But its not working. The point is that is doesnt seem to work just by what is usual like with x = Range("E:E").End(xlDown), and then Wth, End With...by my point of view but im also kind of new in this field

Comment: `Range("E:E").End(xlDown)` has no meaning in VBA. You should use `Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row` to determine the last row and build the range as `Range("E2:E" & lastRow)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have understood, you are using remove duplicates on Col `A` values pasted in Column `D` (*Code not there in question I guess*) and then match the values with Col `A` to collate the values from Col `B` to create a summary kind of thing.

If my understanding is correct then there is a simpler way to do it.

**LOGIC**

1. Identify your range and store the values in an array. This is to speed things up. To identify the range, you can find the last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and then use that range.
2. Create a unique collection of values from Col `A`.
3. Define a second array based on unique values.
4. Compare the unique values with values in Col `A` and collate the values from Col `B`.
5. Clear Column `D` and `E` for output and finally output the array there.
6. Identify the final range to work with. You can then add color, border etc to that range.

**CODE**

I have commented the code but if you still have problems understanding it then do let me know.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyAr As Variant, OutputAr As Variant
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim itm As Variant
    Dim tmpString As String
    Dim rng As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in column A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Store the Col A and B values in an array
        MyAr = .Range("A1:B" & lRow).Value2
        
        '~~> Loop through the array and get unique values from Col A
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add MyAr(i, 1), CStr(MyAr(i, 1))
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With
    
    '~~> Define your output array based on unique values found
    ReDim OutputAr(1 To col.Count, 1 To 2)
      
    j = 1
    '~~> Compare the unique values with values in Col `A`
    '~~> and collate the values from Col `B`
    For Each itm In col
        OutputAr(j, 1) = itm
        
        tmpString = ""
        
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            If MyAr(i, 1) = itm Then
                tmpString = tmpString & "," & MyAr(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i
        
        OutputAr(j, 2) = "'" & Mid(tmpString, 2)
        j = j + 1
    Next itm
    
    With ws
        '~~> Clear Col D and E for output
        .Columns("D:E").Clear
        
        '~~> Output the array
        .Range("D1").Resize(col.Count, 2).Value = OutputAr
        
        '~~> This is the final range
        Set rng = .Range("D1:E" & col.Count)
        
        With rng
            MsgBox .Address
            '
            '~~> Do what you want with the range here
            '
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**IN ACTION**

[image]

An example to **add borders**

```
With rng
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    
    For i = 7 To 12
        With .Borders(i)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

**Output**

[image]

Similarly to **center align the text**

```
With rng
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @Siddarth Rout....well what shall i say..its perfect, solves also the problem with the comma before the first entry...i'm blasted i mean i dont get it how you can do something likes this in 10 mins. I just changed ws to Activesheet ..and now i'm figuring out your updates with the frame..Thanks, really dont know what to say

Comment: Glad it worked out. I would recommend not using `ActiveSheet`. Use the actual sheet name like `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")` or the codename like `Set ws = Sheet1`. Because if the relevant sheet is not active then you will not get the desired results.

Comment: it works perfectally,not joking also with the Center & Borders. The problem about if i do not use ActiveSheet is 1. that in the end the sheet has to be used by a couple of persons, who shall 2. load external data and modify these in Excel for which i create 3 Buttons = 3 Steps...this code here was the 2nd Step. I have to solve this how its easiest but i think rewrite the code in VBA to which each time this code has be assigned to a specific sheet is not that good idea? The 3rd Step is that submit the modyfied data to a Word sheet

Comment: If the data is loaded in the relevant sheet and it is active then there shouldn't be a problem in using activesheet especially if the code is called from a button from that sheet.

Comment: i have a last question if i have further values in column C&D, next to column A & B, would i understand it right that i "just" have to collate further values to A ? '~~> and collate the values from Col `B` so i just copy the code under the comment, modify it to the specific range and this i do 2 times (one time for C, one time for D)?

Comment: If you want values from there as well then yes. If not, then ignore those columns. But remember to specify the correct columns for output else if you use `.Columns("D:E").Clear` then existing data will be lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232693/discussion-between-sven-and-siddharth-rout).